# Error with CMake to generate ITK Module VTKGlue

Tags: cmake, vtk, itk

I want to generate makefiles for ITK module VTKGlue but I have a message error:

> CMake Error at Modules/Bridge/VtkGlue/itk-module-init.cmake:7
>   (find_package):   Could not find a configuration file for package
>   "VTK" that is compatible   with requested version "".
>
> The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
>
> ```
> C:/ITK/bin/VTK/VTKConfig.cmake, version: 6.2.0 (64bit)
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMake/ITKModuleEnablement.cmake:315 (include)   CMakeLists.txt:364
>   (include)

The content of Modules/Bridge/VtkGlue/itk-module-init.cmake is :

> #
>   Find the packages required by this module
>   #
>
> Needed VTK version set(VERSION_MIN "5.10.0")
>
> Look for VTK find_package(VTK NO_MODULE REQUIRED COMPONENTS vtkCommonCore)

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to rebuild VTK...

It has been built with the generator VS, whereas ITK is built with the generator Eclipse CDT.